How to go back to edits in progress after accidently hitting "Execute" instead of "Apply" in MySQL
More than once, I've queried some results in MySql, made a series of edits in the table, and then accidently hit the execute button instead of the apply button. Of course, this reruns the query and makes the edits disappear. Is there a way to return to the previous view when this happens, so the edits aren't simply lost?

If there's not a way to undo the overwrite, perhaps there is a way to disable the execute button when edits are in progress? Obviously, ctrl-z doesn't work for this scenario, and I don't see anything in the dropdown settings, but I'm hoping I've simply overlooked something.

You should post your edit as an answer.

I never edit queries in the Workbench app. I develop SQL scripts and test against a scratch instance until I have it thoroughly tested.

What's interesting to me is I will occasionally get a flash of the pending edits between queries, so I know they still exist, and when I make this mistake and go to close the workbench, it will ask me to review changes, but clicking yes doesn't take me to them.

I've figured out that if I simply comment out my query when I know I'm going to be making a bunch of edits, it effectively disables the overwrite button, so clicking the button does nothing to the existing table or pending edits. Of course, this is not automatic, so it's not the ideal solution.

Edit: Executing a query that is partially highlighted in a way that breaks it, or simply running a broken query will cause the previous view to appear with all its uncommitted edits still in tact:

or

